# Find the parent of a precise child to then select a child with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple example here:

```
<div class = "container">
   <div id = "jwplayer-0_wrapper"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

And so What my code is supposed to do is so look wether or not there's a div with the id of "jwplayer-0_wrapper"

```
 if ($('#'+divId).length == 1 ) {
```

Then I need to select its direct parent, to get to its child>script and make it a .text()  to be able to use the script content inside a variable. So I'm stuck on the selector problem of getting the script content. Maybe there's another way of getting the script with out even using its parent? They will always be inside the same parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my first answer wrong. Select the div, then navigate to the parent and select the text of the 'script' child.

```
$('#' + divId)
    .parent()
    .children('script')
    .text();
```

Comment: No, becasue I can't know what the divId of the parent of `<div id = "jwplayer-0_wrapper"></div>` is here's just an example, but I realy have to make it dynamicly controlled around the "jwplayer-0_wrapper" div

Comment: And I add this infront of a `var scriptText = $('#' + divId).parent().children('script').text();` and it should do?

Comment: I saw what you meant just as I pressed the submit button. :) I edited my answer.

Comment: I'm getting a undefined

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your specific problem:

```
$('#' + divId).next().text() ;
```

Comment: No, this dont do, becasue I can't know what the divId of the parent of <div id = "jwplayer-0_wrapper"></div> is here's just an example, but I realy have to make it dynamicly controlled around the "jwplayer-0_wrapper" div

Comment: This actually will work because you don't need to know the I'd of the parent element. The next()  method in jQuery selects the next sibling element.

Comment: Yes Greg. Short and easy solution when you know the target element is next sibling.

Answer (score 2):

This should work to grab the script tag's inner text.

```
if ($('#'+divId).length == 1 ) {
    var scriptNode = $('#'+divId).parent().find('script').text();
}
```

Comment: can you confirm that divId is a string set to "jwplayer-0_wrapper"?

Comment: The accepted answer worked just fine but thank you for the help